# Compare an $O_p(1)$ with some growing numbers

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

There is a known positive sequence $M_n>0$ (e.g., $M_n = \log(n)$), where $M_n\to\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. If a sequence $X_n$ is $O_p(1)$, then can I claim $\Pr(|X_n| > M_n ) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

It seems to me that this is true because  $\Pr(|X_n| > M_n ) = \Pr(|X_n|/ M_n > 1)$ and $X_n/M_n = O_p(1/M_n) = o_p(1)$. By the definition of $o_p(1)$, $\Pr(|X_n|/ M_n > 1)$ must go to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please format your post according to the guidelines: 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jim. To be as clear as possible, you might want to pay a little more attention to absolute values.  For instance, $-\log(n)$ diverges, too, but $\Pr(|X_n|\gt  -\log(n)) = 1$ for all $n\gt 1.$  BTW, if you right-click over any of the formatted math expressions in this comment, you can view the $\TeX$ expressions that created them, enabling you to clean up your post with a few quick paste operations.  Delimit the $\TeX$ expressions with dollar signs "\$".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. $M_n$ is restricted to be positive.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand why you are introducing the sequence $M_n.$ All you need is a *single* sufficiently large number to apply the definition of $O_p(1).$

Comment: Both the result and your proof are correct.  A little generalization to this result is that "$o_p(1) \cdot O_p(1) = o_p(1)$" (the proof of this is slightly more technical and interesting), which you may want to give it a try).  For those who are not familiar with "$O_p$ and $o_p$" notation, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation).

Comment: **A direct application of definitions** leads to a simpler, clearer proof: $X_n\sim O_p(1)$ means for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $M$ for which $\Pr(|X_n|\ge M)\le \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n.$ $M_n\to\infty$ means that for any $M,$ $M_n\ge M$ for all sufficiently large $n.$ The result is immediate.

Comment: @whuber I think you accidentally reversed the inequality direction inside $\operatorname{Pr}$.  Besides, it is more standard to write $X_n = O_p(1)$ rather than $X_n \sim O_p(1)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks--that's a typo (but a bad one).  I'll fix it.